# SignalR methods in WebApi controller not called in specific setup

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Well, I have a signalR hub:

```
public class ReportHub : Hub
{
    private static IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ReportHub>();
    public void SendMessage(string text)
    {
        Clients.All.sendMessage(text);
    }

    public static void ServerSendMessage(string text)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.All.sendMessage(text);
    }
}
```

Also I have the client code in js, on some view

```
report.client.sendMessage = message => {
    alert('message from server: '+ message);
}
```

And I have webapi action, like this:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Report/test")]
    public int GetTest()
    {
        ReportHub.ServerSendMessage("message");
        return 42;
    }
```

When I open the view with signalR-catching js code in one browser, and in another browser window requesting the webapi action, by typing  http://../api/report/test - all working, and alert is appearing
But when I calling webapi action via postman, or any other rest client, no effect at all,   report.client.sendMessage = message => {
        alert('message from server: '+ message);
    } - not working
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

> ReportHub.ServerSendMessage("message");

It is wrong.

You should return `ReportHubContext` for the connection before pushing the data to clients;

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Report/test")]
public int GetTest()
{
    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ReportHub>();
    hubContext.ServerSendMessage("message");
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: ReportHub.ServerSendMessage("message"); calls for       ReportHubContext inside

Comment: Prevent the GetHubContext to be just one instance and shared by all clients.